# How to get row count between two words in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

Below is the pattern of my source files:

```
Col1
Col2
col3
colN
START-OF-DATA
val1|val2|val3|valN
val1|val2|val3|valN
val1|val2|val3|valN
val1|val2|val3|valN
END-OF-DATA
TIMEFINISHED=Mon Apr 21 20:28:55 EDT 2014
END-OF-FILE
```

I want to find out the row count between START-OF-DATA and END-OF-DATA. Initially I had to do it for one file so I just used

```
V_ROWCOUNT=`wc -l ${V_LOC}/${V_FILENM} | awk -F" " '{print ($1-1)}'`
```

and then subtracted the number of static rows which are not data rows. Now I have to make is generalize and the only common thing in input files is the START-OF-DATA and END-OF-DATA. So I want to find the row count between these tow tags.

Could you please let me know how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with awk:

```
rowcount=$(awk '/END-OF-DATA/{print NR-start; exit} /START-OF-DATA/{start=NR+1}' "$v_loc/$v_filenm")
```

And here's the same, but with START-OF-DATA and END-OF-DATA as variables instead of hardcoding them into the awk script:

```
start=START-OF-DATA end=END-OF-DATA
rowcount=$(awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" '$0 ~ end { print NR - s; exit } $0 ~ start { s = NR + 1 }' "$v_loc/$v_filenm")
```

On a side note, you should avoid using uppercase variables for internal purposes since you risk overriding special shell variables and environment variables.

It's also a good idea to always quote variable expansions when they're used as arguments, to avoid unnecessary word-splitting and pathname expansions occurring on the results.

Comment: Thanks geirha for your answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This statement does it:

```
set -- $(egrep -n 'START-OF-DATA|END-OF-DATA' | cut -d ':' -f1 ); expr $2 - $1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another technique:

```
$ n=$(( $(sed -n '/START-OF-DATA/,/END-OF-DATA/p' file | wc -l) - 2 ))
$ echo $n
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$(grep -n 'END-OF-DATA' data | cut -d: -f1)-$(grep -n 'START-OF-DATA' data | cut -d: -f1)" | bc
```

What this does:

- `grep` for `END-OF-DATA`, including line number

  - Outputs `10:END-OF-DATA`
- `cut` the output, delimited by `:`, get field `1`

  - Outputs `10`
- Repeat for `START-OF-DATA`
- Build that into `10-5` using `echo`
- Pipe it into `bc` (basic calculator) for evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative and more descriptive `awk` example is as follows:

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    begincounting = 0; 
    stopcounting = 0; 
    lines = 0; 
} 
{ 
    if ($1=="START-OF-DATA") { begincounting = 1; } 
    if ($1=="END-OF-DATA") { stopcounting = 1; } 
    if (begincounting==1 && stopcounting==0) { lines++; } 
} 
END {
    print "Total lines: "lines-1
}' test.txt
```

**Explanation**

- `BEGIN { ... }` is where we put some variables or flags.
- Next is the body.
- There we set the flag `begincounting` to 1 if we notice the first column is START-OF-DATA
- We set the flag `stopcounting` to 1 if we notice the first column is END-OF-DATA
- Whenever we notice that `begincounting` is set but `stopcounting` is not set, we increment `lines` variable
- At the end of reading information, we print out the line count minus 1
- Why the minus 1? Remember that `begincounting` flag causes `lines` to be incremented as soon as `START-OF-DATA` is found. That means - line containing START-OF-DATA is also counted

Hope this helps someone in the future.